# Correct way to translate ES6 "import" to nodejs "require"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, browserify

I'm tryng to reproduce the example reported [here](https://github.com/alexcurtis/react-treebeard#quick-start) inside my project.
The problem is that I'm using Browseryfy that seems to not support ES6 imports.
So I thought of translate the third import of the example from:

```
import {Treebeard} from 'react-treebeard';
```

to

```
var Treebeard = require('react-treebeard').default;
```

But it still not works, and I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected
>   a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: undefined

I read of trying to switch to babelify but I will consider this option as very last.
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var Treebeard = require('react-treebeard').Treebeard;
```